# When using pandas is it possible to replace the re package with the regex package?

Tags: regex, pandas

I want to take advantage of the mrab `regex` functionality to give me access to its Levenshtein capabilities.  Pandas throws an error because it does not seem to recognise the regex drop-in.

From what I can gather, it is failing this test and that is throwing it off:

`isinstance(obj, Pattern)`

It has been almost impossible to search for help because of the module name.

Is this something that can be worked around, or is it simply beyond the optimisation in pandas and therefore a job for apply()?

Comment: It is a job for `apply`. You can't force Pandas to use `regex` instead of `re`.

Comment: Thanks.  I had suspected that, but wanted to double check.